# NSStringEncoding - enum to string to enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

So I'm saving the `NSString` encoding enum value in a database as a string. This is one of the values:

```
 NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
```

And I'm saving it as a string with value `0x94000100`. My goal is to read this value as an NSString, but then turn it into a value I can use to encode:

```
        NSString* encodingValueAsString = [object objectForKey:kWSWordlistFilesEncodingKey];

        // Convert 'encodingValueAsString' to variable 'encoding' that can act as enum

        NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                             encoding:encoding];
```

How do I write that missing line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to convert the `enum` value to/from a string. Just save it and read it back as an `int`.

But the short answer to your original question is:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding = [encodingValueAsString intValue];
```

Wait - that won't work since you are saving the string as the hex value.

You need to use `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:encodingValueAsString];
NSStringEncoding encoding;
[scanner scanHexInt:&encoding];
```

See why using `int` instead of a string would be easier?